Dax measure that returns value based on calculated min
Hi I managed to create a measure that sums count by ID and then returns the min between the 2 the logic would be sum(id=1)=600 sum(id=2)=700 so return 600. What I want is to be able to create a measure that returns the Id with the min value (id=1) and I cannot get it to work.
My current measure is

Min_value =
 Var x1= calculate(sum(count), id=1)
 Var x2 = calculate(sum(count),        id=2) 
 Return min(x1,x2) 

This is what I tried

`Min_value_id =
Varw x1= calculate(sum(count), id=1)
Var x2 = calculate(sum(count), id=2) 
X3= min(x1,x2)  
Return calculate(max(id), sum(count)=x3) 
`


It doesn’t seem to like the sum(count) =x3, can anyone advise how to fix this? Thanks!



count
id




200
1


400
2


400
1


500
2




you can try this
sum = sum('Table'[count])

min_sum = minx(values('Table'[id]),[sum])

min_id =
VAR _tbl =
    SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', 'Table'[id], "sum1", SUM ( 'Table'[count] ) )
VAR _tbl2 =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( _tbl, "check", IF ( MINX ( _tbl, [sum1] ) = [sum1], 1 ) )
RETURN
    MAXX ( FILTER ( _tbl2, [check] = 1 ), [id] )


